# Formula workshop - formula editor in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have something like this

quantuty 10,10,15,20,30
price per piece 2,2,5,7,4

I want to calculate total price for each row and sum all this

I use formula

```
Sum ({ESTIMATE_ITEMS.QUANTITY} * {ESTIMATE_ITEMS.PRICE_PER_PIECE} )
```

And I got an error mesage for this formula "A field is required here"

So what is wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a formula on each row that does the multiplication, then you can insert a summary summation on that formula field. In other words, take out the sum from your formula and save the formula, insert the formula as a field. Right click on the formula field and choose "insert summary" then choose "sum".

Comment: You're welcome. If my response answered your question then please mark it as the answer. :)